# Jumpy behavior on Transition Property

Tags: javascript, css

I am having trouble transitioning the width and height of an image. The image is supposed to appear small and then grow in size. However, when I add the second class, to transition the height and width, the image jumps to the next width and height without transitioning the properties. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help!

I delayed the addition of the second class containing the adjusted CSS rules as I thought that adding the classes back to back was causing an error. After setting the delay with setTimeout() the function seems to appear slightly better as the image appears to move some but not in the intended way.

```
<div><img src="Some String"></div>
```

```
.lightbox-img { width: 100%; } 

.light-box-small { 
  width: 20vw; 
  height: 10vh; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  transition: width 1s ease-in; 
  transition: height 1s ease-in; }

.lightbox-container { width: 60vw; height: 30vh; }
```

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.img'); 
const backdrop = document.querySelector('.backdrop'); 
const lightboxImg = document.createElement('img'); 
const container = document.createElement('div'); 

images.forEach(image => { 
  image.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    lightboxImg.src = image.src; 
    container.appendChild(lightboxImg); 
    container.classList.add('light-box-small'); 
    lightboxImg.classList.add('lightbox-img'); 
    backdrop.classList.add('dim'); 
    document.body.appendChild(container);

     setTimeout(() => { 
      container.classList.add('lightbox-container'); 
     }, 500); 
   }); 
 });
```

The expected result should be as follows:
  1. The image appears in the center of the viewport 
  2. The image grows from the smaller size to the larger size.

The error is occurring on step 2 and jumps to the next width instead of transitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you C14L for offering help. Unfortunately applying the transition rules to the lightbox-container didn't work.

The problem turned out to be that when I declared the 2 CSS transition rules the second rule would overwrite the first rule. By declaring the rule in one declaration they wont override each other. So the solution is:

```
.light-box-small {
  transition: width 1s ease-in, height 1s ease-in;
}
```